# Read huge binary numbers in Scala

Tags: scala, binary, decimal, bigint

I have 2 huge numbers written in a .txt file in binary format. Both of them have about 800 digits. I want to read them from this file in Scala, but I can't find a suitable type, which would be able to hold all the digits. It seems that even BigInt cuts a part of the digits. 
The task itself is to add to numbers in binary representation and count zeroes/ones. I wanted to operate with String, so it would be easier to convert from binary to a decimal system.
So I would be grateful for any advice on which type to use better in Scala for such numbers?

Comment: How did you determine that "BigInt cuts a part of the digits"? `new BigInteger(theNumberAsAString, 2)` should be able to read it no matter how long the number is.

Comment: are you sure that the expected solution is to convert into decimal, execute the operation, then convert it back to binary and count the ones? it sounds more like an exercise where they expect you to implement manually the binary addition with fold or something like that